# AngularJS templating and making it faster?

Tags: javascript, django, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS in combination with Django to make single-page application. In general, I have index page (search) and details page with more sub-pages.

And that makes a problem. I have one controller (for details and it is getting info about object which is chosen) and other controllers user that main controller using `$controller` function.

It looks like:

```
.controller('BuildingDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'buildingsRepository', '$location',
   function($scope, $routeParams, buildingsRepository, $location) {

        $scope.details = null;
        $scope.menu = templatesFolder + "buildings/menus/";
        $scope.currentUrl = $location.url();
        $scope.loading = true;

        buildingsRepository.getDetails($routeParams.slug).then(function(res) {
            $scope.details = res.data[0];
            $scope.loading = false;
        });

        $scope.alert = {"type": null, "message": null};

  }])

  .controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'buildingsRepository', '$location', '$controller',
   function($scope, $routeParams, buildingsRepository, $location, $controller) {

        $controller('BuildingDetailsCtrl', {$scope: $scope, $routeParams: $routeParams, buildingsRepository: buildingsRepository, $location: $location})
        $scope.partial = templatesFolder + "buildings/details/info.html";
  }])
```

and my urls:

```
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: templatesFolder + "buildings/index.html", controller: 'UserBuildingsCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/details/:slug', {templateUrl: templatesFolder + "buildings/details.html", controller: 'BuildingInfoCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/test/:slug', {templateUrl: templatesFolder + "buildings/details.html", controller: 'SecondCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.when('/contact/:slug', {templateUrl: templatesFolder + "buildings/details.html", controller: 'BuildingContactCtrl'});
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
}]);
```

On that `details.html`page, I have one menu, but problem is loading, and everytime I change from, for example, InfoCtrl to SecondCtrl, my menu is being refreshed and I can see that (less than half second). It is irritating.

Is there any way to prevent loading of those templates, to load just partial, but with changing URL (I need it to be accessed from copied url etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can [embed](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) your template in the already-rendered page as a script of type `text/ng-template`:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="details.html">
  <p>hello world</p>
</script>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G3BrgGnzv1NRYNfdjD1C?p=preview) is a plunk.

---

You should not need to call `$controller()` in your controller. You angular app will instance the controller needed by including a directive in your html like this:

```
<div ng-controller="BuildingDetailsCtrl">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have it, I just use ng-include, but my site is being refreshed every time

Comment: You have it embedded in the page? The only reasons it would be slow are: 1) the browser is ajaxing the template into the page, 2) there is bad/slow code. Assuming #1 is your issue, the embedded template should resolve it.

Comment: Yes, I have details.html page with included menu, and you see, I bind partial to $scope and then I show that partial on my page, but it is so slow. **And yes, browser is every time sending new request. How to resolve it**

Comment: this line: `$controller('BuildingDetailsCtrl', {$scope: $scope, $routeParams: $routeParams, buildingsRepository: buildingsRepository, $location: $location})` -- what's that doing? In your template html, you can specify the controller via `ng-controller` directive, like this: `<div ng-controller="BuildingDetailsCtrl">`

Comment: My answer should resolve the reloading-every-time problem, by embedding that template in the page. Once it's loaded once, it's compiled into templateCache as well (optimizing it a little more).

Comment: It is just inheriting main controller, which is getting required information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54310/discussion-between-j-wells-and-harisb2012).